# Example on Correspondences

Tags: convex-analysis

Giva an example of correspondence $F : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ such that the closure of $F$ is $ \overline{F}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$, upper semi continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, but $F$ is not, if any.

I got stuck with this question. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\mto{\multimap}\def\R{\mathbb R}$Define $F \colon \R \mto \R$ by 
$$ F(x) = \begin{cases} [0, 1] & x > 0\\ [0,1) & x \le 0\end{cases} $$
Then $F$ isn't upper semi-continuous, as $(-1,1)$ is an open neighbourhood of $F(0)$, but for each open neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ we have $F(U) \not\subseteq (-1,1)$. The closure 
$$ \bar F(x) = [0,1], \quad x \in \mathbb R $$
is upper semi-continuous, as it is constant.